# LINQ sub list<> sometimes returns "NULL"

Tags: c#, linq

I have a LINQ query with a sublist in it which sometimes can return no returns, however can't manage to get the actual null instead of a error.
Any help in this would be appriciated.

```
        var member_settings = from ml in _pMetaLanguages
                     join s in _settings
                     on ml.id equals s.setting_type_id
                              orderby ml.name descending
                     select new _class {
                         group_name = ml.name
                         , code = (ml.classes.Where(c => c.id == s.int_value)).FirstOrDefault().code
                         , name = (ml.classes.Where(c => c.id == s.int_value)).FirstOrDefault().name
                         , id = (ml.classes.Where(c => c.id == s.int_value)).FirstOrDefault().id
                         ,
                         classUI = ml.metadataMUI
                         ,
                         nameUI = ml.metadataMUI.Where(u => u.language_type_id.Equals(list_language_id))
                           .Select(i => new pMetaClasses
                           {
                               name = i.classes.Where(y => (y.bound_id.Equals(list_language_id))).FirstOrDefault().name
                           }).FirstOrDefault().name
                         , setting_type_id = s.setting_type_id
                         , int_value = s.int_value 
                     };
```

EDITED

This part delivers the problems

```
nameUI = ml.metadataMUI.Where(u => u.language_type_id.Equals(list_language_id))
                       .Select(i => new pMetaClasses
                       {
                           name = i.classes.Where(y => (y.bound_id.Equals(list_language_id))).FirstOrDefault().name
                       }).FirstOrDefault().name
```

"metadataMUI" sometimes has records but not always, when no records it should be null (at least no error...

Comment: What sub classes are talking about? i.classes? Try rewriting it as follows: name = i.classes == null ? String.Empty : <your code>. BTW, why do you mix different LINQ notations in one query?

Comment: `.FirstOrDefault()` will not save you from NullReferenceException if you are trying to access a property of a null-object.

Comment: It would really help if you'd show a short but *complete* example, preferrably without the odd layout of commas at the start of lines, and simplified as far as possible while still showing what's going wrong.

Comment: Sorry, understand that its unclear...))                          nameUI = ml.metadataMUI.Where(u => u.language_type_id.Equals(list_language_id))
                           .Select(i => new pMetaClasses
                           {
                               name = i.classes.Where(y => (y.bound_id.Equals(list_language_id))).FirstOrDefault().name
                           }).FirstOrDefault().name

Comment: @xiaoy312, that I noticed but can manage to avoid the null reference, any suggestions how to? Searched whole afternoon and seems I am the only one who has this problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a collection of objects, it may or may not be empty.  You want to pull out a property from the first item in that collection, if there is one.  Currently whenever your query is face with this problem you are using this general approach:

```
sequence.FirstOrDefault().SomeMember
```

This code works fine if the sequence will always contain an item.  It doesn't work if it may be empty.  (Unless you can and want to get the member of the default value.  For reference types, as you clearly are working with, this just results in null reference excpetions.)  Fortunately there is a simple transformation to ensure that this works correctly.  Simply use `Select` to transform the sequence into the sub-property that you are interested in and *then* get the first or default value of that sequence:

```
sequence.Select(item => item.SomeMember).FirstOrDefault();
```

This will work properly whether there are items or no items.  The projection will never be called on default values using this approach.

Of course you do this in a lot of places, so you'll need to make this transformation throughout your query.